# The sample in the table by entering the words longer than the 20-character(in mysql)

Tags: mysql, regex, select

Hello the question is this - there is a table with fields `model` and `id`. The field `model` can store a few words of different lengths, separated by a space. For example, *"some arbitrary model name"* or *"суперпупердлинноеназваниемодели a mistake."* I must select the records in which at least one word in the model name is longer than 22 characters. So, the first model does not fall in the result set, and the second one does. I tried this but the selection is not working correctly.

```
SELECT id, model FROM table1 WHERE model REGEXP "[А-Яа-яa-zA-Z]{22,}"
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what result are you expecting but not getting? Is this query returning too many records or too few? It seems to work as expected for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9421/1

Comment: For example, there is a value models, 1) "some var opt", 2) 'thebestvalueofthewordforme or other', I expect to have a second value of the sample, because in the second model name of one of the words model names on the length of more than 22 characters

Comment: If you go to the sqlfiddle link I gave you, your current query is indeed giving that result and not the 1) result. So it looks to me that the query is already working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL to retrieve only rows with characters more than 22.

...select * FROM table WHERE char_length(model) > 22

Comment: This is not an option. Because in the same field may be located a few words and do not need to determine the length of the field, and the longest word in the field. And the length of the longest field to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your `WHERE` clause to use the `alnum` character class I belive that will give you what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE model REGEXP "[[:alnum:]]{22,}"
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd386/4/0).

(Or replace the character class with `alpha` if you know the model "word" never contains numerics.)

Comment: here's a screenshot http://listick.ru/share/wD6SI of the query (SELECT id, menutitle
FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE menutitle REGEXP '[A-Za-Z] {20,}'), but if that's here is the same query works correctly http://sqlfiddle.com/ #! 2/766f0a/1 Why is this happening I can not understand. Encoding tables and databases - utf8_general_ci

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can be much help there. I'd hoped `[:alnum:]` or `[:alpha:]` would get around any encoding problems, but clearly not.